# Kafka Schema registry - Advertise dynamic port in container

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, nomad

As I understand, while using Schema registry confluent docker image ( not with zookeeper resiliency, but with kafka resiliency), we can advertise the hostname of the container to Kafka by using the `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME` env variable.

If I try to use the `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT`, 
I get the following error :

```
PORT is deprecated. Please use SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS instead.
```

Why cannot we set the port associated ?
I can get this dynamic port ( the dynamic port the host machine mapped dynamically to my container) but how am I supposed to share it with Kafka ?

EDIT 1 :

To add more details, here is an example of assignment made by the schema registry coordinator :

```
[2019-10-25 11:55:47,813] INFO Finished rebalance with master election result: Assignment{version=1, error=0, master='sr-1-7a9a403a-63cc-4fed-b548-10ea440863d5', masterIdentity=version=1,host=10.135.124.179,port=29932,scheme=http,masterEligibility=true} (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.masterelector.kafka.KafkaGroupMasterElector)
```

As you can see there is a **hostname** and a **port** ( in bold).
The **hostname** comes from the variable `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME` but according to the code, the **port** comes from here :

```
/**
   * A Schema Registry instance's identity is in part the port it listens on. Currently the port can
   * either be configured via the deprecated `port` configuration, or via the `listeners`
   * configuration.
   *
   * <p>This method uses `Application.parseListeners()` from `rest-utils` to get a list of
   * listeners, and returns the port of the first listener to be used for the instance's identity.
   *
   * <p></p>In theory, any port from any listener would be sufficient. Choosing the first, instead
   * of say the last, is arbitrary.
   */
  // TODO: once RestConfig.PORT_CONFIG is deprecated, remove the port parameter.
  static SchemeAndPort getSchemeAndPortForIdentity(int port, List<String> configuredListeners,
                                                   String requestedScheme)
```

( https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/5af0ca3be1138fe483d0f90f4ccfd4f02f158334/core/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/storage/KafkaSchemaRegistry.java#L211-L223 )

So the only way to advertize the port is by setting it using the listeners, which can be annoying ( but still feasible as a workaround).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I made a working Nomad template file, maybe this might help. The workaround is to use the same dynamic port that nomad use for port mapping, inside the container, as follows :

```
job "schema-registry" {
  datacenters = ["YOURDC"]
  type = "service"

  # Update strategy
  update {
    # Max instances (task groups) to be updated in parallel.
    max_parallel = 1

    # Once an allocation finishes, wait min_healthy_time until starting next one.
    min_healthy_time = "10s"

    # If allocation not healthy after healthy_deadline, mark as unhealthy.
    healthy_deadline = "3m"

    # If allocation unhealthy after progress_deadline, fail the deployment.
    progress_deadline = "10m"

    # Should auto revert to previous version if the deployment fails?
    auto_revert = false

    # Create n canaries.
    canary = 0
  }

  spread {
    attribute = "${attr.unique.hostname}"
    weight    = 100
  }

  migrate {
    # As in update stanza.
    max_parallel = 1

    # "checks" for health checks or "task_state" for task state.
    health_check = "checks"

    # As in update stanza.
    min_healthy_time = "10s"

    # As in update stanza.
    healthy_deadline = "5m"
  }

  # The "group" stanza defines a series of tasks that should be co-located on
  # the same Nomad client.
  group "schema-registry-group" {

    # count of instances of the "schema-registry" task group
    count = 3

    restart {
      # The number of attempts to run the job within the specified interval.
      attempts = 2
      interval = "30m"

      # The "delay" parameter specifies the duration to wait before restarting
      # a task after it has failed.
      delay = "5s"

      # What if after a few restats within `interval` the `attempts` limit is meet?
      # - "delay" mode delays the next restart until the next interval,
      # - "fail" mode does not restart the task.
      mode = "fail"
    }

    # Use ephemeral disk shared between tasks instead of HDD
    ephemeral_disk {
      size = 300
    }

    task "schema-registry" {
      driver = "docker"

      # Driver (docker) settings.
      config {
        image = "confluentinc/cp-schema-registry"

        # We cannot use this as schema registry will use the LISTENERS config to advertize its port..
        #port_map {
        #  schema_registry_port = 8081
        #}
      }

      # Time to shut down after SIGINT.
      # Caution! If want to set higher than 30s,
      # make sure max_kill_timeout allows that.
      kill_timeout = "30s"
      kill_signal = "SIGINT"
      shutdown_delay = "2s"

      env {
        SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="YOURBOOTSTRAPSERVER"
        SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME="${NOMAD_IP_schema_registry_port}"
        SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS="http://0.0.0.0:${NOMAD_HOST_PORT_schema_registry_port}"
      }

      # Max required storage = (max_files * 2) * max_file_size
      # *2 because there's a log file for stderr and stdout
      logs {
         max_files     = 10
         max_file_size = 15
       }

      # Required resources.
      resources {
        cpu    = 500 # 500 MHz
        memory = 512
        network {
          port "schema_registry_port" {} # defined in port_map
        }
      }

      service {
        name = "schema-registry"
        tags = ["schema-registry"]
        port = "schema_registry_port"
        check {
          name     = "alive"
          type     = "tcp"
          interval = "60s"
          timeout  = "4s"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`listeners` takes the bind-address **and port(s)**, and as you found the advertised one is `the port of the first listener to be used for the instance's identity`

> Comma-separated list of listeners that listen for API requests over either HTTP or HTTPS. If a listener uses HTTPS, the appropriate SSL configuration parameters need to be set as well.
>
> Schema Registry identities are stored in ZooKeeper and are made up of a hostname and port. If multiple listeners are configured, the first listener's port is used for its identity.
>
> Type: list
>      Default: "http://0.0.0.0:8081"

https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/installation/config.html#listeners

Comment: Not sure you understand my question, I'm not saying Kafka or zookeeper is sending anything, I'm saying that Schema registry is advertising its hostname and port to Kafka/ZK to make the other schema registry nodes be aware of the others SR nodes ( and thus the master). I will edit my post to make it clear

Comment: If I understood the question, you have some dynamic port mapping externally to the container, and you might not be able to control what that value is? Anecdotally, I have a similar situtation with Marathon, and I had to template out the property file at runtime to apply two listener ports via other environment variables... One listens externally (PORT_8081 provided by Marathon), and internally (REGISTRY_PORT) `listeners=http://0.0.0.0:{{ .Env.PORT_8081 }},http://0.0.0.0:{{ default .Env.REGISTRY_PORT "8081" }}`